# Jolt transformation to keep just the array of elements

Tags: json, jolt

I need to create a pretty simple jolt transformation to convert the following json:

```
{
  "pfr_item": [
    {
      "field1": "value1"
    },
    {
      "field2": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Into the following one:

```
[{
        "field1": "value1"
    },
    {
        "field2": "value2"
    }
]
```

I've been having a look at some jolt examples and trying to create my own shift transformation for a while but can't make it work. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this JSON Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[]"
      }
    }
  }
]
```